# Django query as string array from checkboxes form

Tags: jquery, django, url-parameters

I would like to get multiple inputs from a checkboxes form something and then filter it out from my database. That would be something similar to:

`http://127.0.0.1:8000/data/?class_type=[class_C,class_M]`

However what I am receiving from the query is:

`http://127.0.0.1:8000/data/?class_type=class_C&class_type=class_M`

This is how it is coded, in **.html**:

```
Data class <br> 
<div class="form-check">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="class_C" id="class_C" name="class_type">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="class_C">
        C
    </label>
</div>

<div class="form-check">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="class_M" id="class_M" name="class_type">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="class_M">
        M
    </label>
</div>

<div class="form-check">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="class_X" id="class_X" name="class_type">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="class_X">
        X
    </label>
</div>
```

In **views.py**:

```
data_class = request.GET.get('class_type')

 [...]

if data_class == "class_C":
    database = database.filter(class_l__contains = "C")
elif data_class == "class_M":
    database = database.filter(class_l__contains = "M")
elif data_class == "class_X":
    database = database.filter(class_l__contains = "X")
```

Any help is pretty appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can obtain the list with [**`.getlist(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.getlist):

```
from django.db.models import Q

data_classes = request.GET.getlist('class_type')

acceptable_values = {'class_C', 'class_M', 'class_X'}

if all(data_class in acceptable_values for data_class in data_classes):
    query = Q(*[Q(('class_l_contains', value)) for value in data_classes])
    database = database.filter(query)
```

or for a logical OR:

```
from django.db.models import Q

data_classes = request.GET.getlist('class_type')

acceptable_values = {'class_C', 'class_M', 'class_X'}

if all(data_class in acceptable_values for data_class in data_classes):
    query = Q(
        *[Q(('class_l_contains', value)) for value in data_classes],
        _connector=Q.OR
    )
    database = database.filter(query)
```

Comment: Solved, thank you. 

I just modified `query = Q()` prior to the loop, and then  `query = query | Q(class_l__contains=data_class)` and works perfectly

Comment: @AngeldelPino: ah, you want a logical *OR*, not a logical *AND*?